# Sorting a string field numerically as numbers ES

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a field that is string type. It always contrains numbers

`"id": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
                  }`

such as 12, 111, 113, 2. Currently it sorts like 111, 113, 12, 2. 
But I cant change field type to nuber

How can I sort as numbers without changing `id` to another type
Maybe some sorting exists in ES?

Comment: You can resort to [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting), but depending on how many documents you have, performance might suffer. The real solution is to reindex your data and give the `id` field a proper data type.

Comment: which es are you running and whats case_insensitive_sort analyzer

Comment: version_number: 2.3.5. And I actually dont know what `case_insensitive_sort` means. It is just snapshot of my es index

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to sort a number which is stored in a string. It worked for me.

```
//Order to sort the list. Can be fetched as an  input field
var sortOrder= "asc";

var sortDescriptor = new SortScriptDescriptor<MyDocument>();

//Query to sort which can be customised
var sortQuery = sortDescriptor                 
               .Type("number")
               .Order(sortOrder == "asc" ? Nest.SortOrder.Ascending : Nest.SortOrder.Descending).Script(sc => sc
               .Source("Float.parseFloat(doc[\"numbered-number\"].value)"));

var result = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
                   .Index("yourIndexName")
                   .Sort(so => sortQuery)
              );
```